# Angular2: How to pass object into a state using ui-router

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to be able to pass an object to a state using ui router. How can I do this?

I am using this to submit my object to a next state:

```
this.uiRouter.stateService.go('example', { object: { title: 'my object' }}, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a service for this. e.g. save state to service on first step, then navigate, then fetch state from service and continue.

Comment: Thanks. I created a shared service for this.